# How to encrypt/decrypt a password using StandardPBEStringEncryptor?

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt password in my application using StandardPBEStringEncryptor. However I think the code I am using is resulting in a memory leak. Am I using this correctly?

```
public static String getPassword(String seed, String encryptedPwd) {
  StandardPBEStringEncryptor pes = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
  pes.setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
  pes.setPassword(seed);
  String originalPwd = pes.decrypt(encryptedPwd);
  return originalPwd;
```

}

```
public static String getDecryptedString( String encryptedPwd) {
   return MyClass.getPassword( 'mypassword', encryptedPwd);
}
```

I use the getDecryptedString() method everywhere in the application for decryption of passwords. 
Does having 2 static methods like above cause a memory leak?

Comment: This looked like Java so I tagged it as such. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why do you believe a memory leak is caused? Have you profiled your application or are you just concerned by the look of the code?